# How to exlude target directory in Gulp task

Tags: gulp

My file structure looks like this

```
app
  src
  target
  file.txt
  anotherfile.txt
```

I have the following Gulp task and I want to keep everything from the src directory and root level files and exclude the entire target directory:

```
  return gulp.src([pathToSourceCode + '/**/*', '!' + pathToSourceCode + '/target/**}'])
    ... Some other tasks ...
    // Output to /dist directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

I'm able to grab everything in src and file parallel to src, but I'm not able to exclude the target directory using this method. Why doesn't this work? The target directory and all its contents appear in the /dist output.

Answer (score 0):

this should work perfectly

```
return gulp.src(['app/**/*', '!app/target/**/*'])
```

also there is a "}" in your gulp.src , it might be causing the problem

```
  return gulp.src([pathToSourceCode + '/**/*', '!' + pathToSourceCode + '/target/**}'])
```

Comment: This still copies over the target directory but it's empty. How do I exclude the target directory entirely?

Comment: try this     return gulp.src(['app/**/*', '!app/target'])